# How to instal php svm and libsvm (mac)?

Tags: php, macos, svm, libsvm

I'm trying to instal php SVM and LIBSVM on mac, I'm using mamp pro with many php different versions.

Answer (score 0):

See for yourself:
http://php.net/manual/en/svm.setup.php

If you follow these steps, and have concrete problems which you can't solve yourself, then reply again.

Also a question would be: Does it has to be php SVM or are you just needing a SVM Framework?

Comment: Thank you,the installation in [Requirements - Manual] (http://php.net/manual/en/svm.requirements.php) is for linux, 

wget http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/cgi-bin/libsvm.cgi?+http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm+tar.gz 
tar xvzf libsvm-3.1.tar.gz 
cd libsvm-3.1
make lib 
cp libsvm.so.1 /usr/lib 
ln -s libsvm.so.1 libsvm.so 
ldconfig 
ldconfig --print | grep libsvm


and  the error “ldconfig: command not found” comes at 
ldconfig

Comment: I thought your intention is to install svm on the virtual server of mamp pro, which sould be a linux server?

If you want to install LibSVM on your Mac and use that sources on your PHP Server, here is the link: https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/

Just follow the steps in the ReadMe file. I did it on my Mac 3 years ago for matlab, wasn't that hard.